What is the associated verb for a civil partnership?
“My friends are getting married [at their wedding].”
“My friends are getting _________ [at their civil partnership].”
What is the correct verb? United? Partnered? Unionised?
There doesn’t seem to be any dictionary definition.

I don't think there's a verb for this. You would probably say

My friends are having a civil partnership ceremony.

The fact that they're being joined together in the partnership is implied, there's no need for a verb (just like you can say a couple is "having a wedding", it's obvious that they're getting married during it).

That's what I did on January 16th this year, with my opposite-sex partner of 32 years (had a civil partnership ceremony). We 'became civil partners' too.

Congratulations!
